# How to promote named tuple fields to variable and associated value?

Tags: julia

I have a model with many parameters where I am passing them as a named tuple. Is there a way to promote the values into the variable scope in my function?

```
parameters = (
    τ₁ = 0.035,   
    β₁ = 0.00509, 
    θ = 1,
    τ₂ = 0.01,    
    β₂ = 0.02685,
    ... 
)
```

And then used like so currently:

```
function model(init,params) # params would be the parameters above
    foo = params.β₁ ^ params.θ 
end
```

Is there a way (marco?) to get the parameters into my variable scope directly so that I can do this:

```
function model(init,params) # params would be the parameters above
    @promote params # hypothetical macro to bring each named tuple field into scope
    foo = β₁ ^ θ 
end
```

The latter looks a lot nicer with some math-heavy code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `@unpack` from the [`UnPack.jl`](https://github.com/mauro3/UnPack.jl) package<sup>1</sup>:

```
julia> nt = (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3);

julia> @unpack a, c = nt; # selectively unpack a and c

julia> a
1

julia> c
3
```

<sup>1</sup> This was formerly part of the [`Parameters.jl`](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl) package, which still exports `@unpack` and has other similar functionality you might find useful.

---

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, writing a general macro `@unpack x` is not possible since the fieldnames are runtime information. You could however define a macro specific to your own type/namedtuple that unpacks

```
julia> macro myunpack(x)
           return esc(quote
               a = $(x).a
               b = $(x).b
               c = $(x).c
               nothing
           end)
       end;

julia> nt = (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3);

julia> @myunpack nt

julia> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```

However, I think it is more clear to use the `@unpack` since this version "hides" assignments and it is not clear where the variables `a`, `b` and `c` comes from when reading the code.

Comment: Is there a way to `@unpack` without declaring which to unpack? Using the example here it seems not: `@unpack nt` => `ERROR: type Symbol has no field head`

Comment: If you think about it, there can be no such macro without providing "target names" like `@unpack` does. The field names of a value are runtime information, only present via the type, and hence inaccessible to a macro.

Comment: You could, however, write a macro that is specific to your own struct/named tuple. Edited the answer with an example.

Comment: Or write [a macro that writes that macro for you](https://gist.github.com/phipsgabler/a1f6b3acac8a664bd4e72cbb2a5e4993) :P